# Discriminate Union based on array literals

Tags: typescript

I would like to compute an union from the existing union using literals in array.

Is it possible?

**Example**

```
interface Intf1 {
    type: "one";
    data: {
        param: boolean;
    };
}

interface Intf2 {
    type: "two";
    data: string;
}

interface Intf3 {
    type: "three";
    data: {
        param: number;
    };
}

const registered = ["one", "two"] as const;

type CombinedIntf = Intf1 | Intf2 | Intf3;

type CustomIntersect = ? 

const getObj = () => {
    return {} as any; // impl 
};

const obj: CustomIntersect<CombinedIntf, typeof registered> = getObj();
// Intf1 | Intf2

switch(obj.type) {
    case "one":
        console.log(obj.data.param);
    break;

    case "two":
        console.log(obj.param);
    break;

    case "three": // should give an error ""three" is not comparable to type "one", "two""
        console.log(obj.param);
    break;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want this way:

```
type CustomIntersect<T, R extends readonly PropertyKey[]> =
  Extract<T, { type: R[number] }>
```

Here I'm using the built-in [`Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) which returns all the elements of a union `T` that are assignable to `U`.  Since you want the second type argument `R` to be the type of an array of keys, we will get the union of its element types by [looking up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) it's `number`-keyed properties, as `R[number]`.  By `Extract`ing all members of the `T` union that are assignable to `{type: R[number]}`, we should grab just those members you care about:

```
const obj: CustomIntersect<CombinedIntf, typeof registered> = getObj();
// const obj: Intf1 | Intf2

switch (obj.type) {
  case "one":
    console.log(obj.data.param);
    break;

  case "two":
    console.log(obj.data.toUpperCase()); // <-- changed this
    break;

  case "three": // error!
    // ~~~~~~~
    // Type '"three"' is not comparable to type '"one" | "two"'.(2678)
    break;
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQElJwIyoN7CqoQCeADlAFyoBEA9mFDQNyGoAmCEC1BRRZBDAQBbagCM6dADZQEYVkQC+rJcFCRYiFBiwAmfG1IVqNCAHc6LNp27UAzhBjgA5qvXho8ZGkwQ4AMyGRMZUtBAAFjBQTIocXDzB-ILCYqhgAK4i4rBxKsBqwEgMjqjRLiCOsFDsqAC8qADa9Iw0ADThljQAuqgI9qjFYI6swKGoAMJ02eA1fnD1uv64AD5LcAZr8wGj4xMZjtN+sPZQSBAAPAAqHQBKqFAAHtBg7APRCOwM0iSoAAowOgUGCkADSUBIjW6AD56mwAKLPYTna4dPDEchhW6NTLZWC9JTQ9RDUouKAQADy4gAVosABQASnqsL4ZXJGRgYHwSj6A3kJGYqAA9ELUCARGRpKgCqMSRBUHQadR9ocRMcYKcUVMZox2PMOqE6AtypUvDVYQ0yZSaYzWCLBiV5YrqdR5qt1np1PZzCAIEgIqg6c6AHShJmspD9NAtJiUNhEEkyKDB6R0FxBmnB2wIYMpUQMuJEcQfADWowTUc6Vjj-AdwyTKbTGepWYSoboAFUyMCJlHGQXhaKLgBaYeDCLyMm1SKVeOoYtyMvqCuncJRGI0aj22CAmAAQjn9oAfifT0fD6KrpjUAByMzrpg3sUDMB0eXFCVCBDiWTEOgYihbxjGhUDWMwuhvYM6T0AA2AB2AAOBk5wXBAlyUIA)

Comment: It is very interesting you can use **Extract** function in such scenario. Sadly typescript documentation only tells about usage against primitive & non-union types. Also **PropertyKey** is not even documented. Clever.